# Using Instagram API- Can anyone give me short steps of how to

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have created an account and also in overview part of developer part of instagram website tried creating an app, and succeeded. yet so far i have no idea how to obtain my client id and then token authorization code.

So it would be awesome if someone cane guide me in bulletine on in short how to do it. I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance :)